# SED : Remove last four characters from filename

Tags: linux, sed

I had list of files in the folder named test_images as below

```
006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg
008299bathmassagesponges-3packa1a4.jpg
008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste125d.jpg
8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g1005.jpg
```

i want to rename all file by removing last four characters from each of them as

```
006103insettedryshampoo-blossom.jpg
008299bathmassagesponges-3pack.jpg
008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste.jpg
8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g.jpg
```

How can i do it using sed ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your file names don't have spaces, you can: (under your `test_images` dir)

```
ls -1|sed -r 's/(.*)....(\.jpg)$/mv & \1\2/'
```

to check the generated `mv` command. If it is ok, add `|sh` to the above command to do the actual renaming.

If your filenames have spaces, you need add quotes:

```
..../mv "&" "\1\2"/'|sh
```

This is a quick and dirty solution, since working with ls result is not good practice.

### update: add "how to" example:

```
LsyHP 11:41:40 /tmp/test/img
kent$  ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kent kent 120 Jan  4 11:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 kent kent 160 Jan  4 11:41 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 008299bathmassagesponges-3packa1a4.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste125d.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g1005.jpg
LsyHP 11:41:43 /tmp/test/img
kent$  ls -1|sed -r 's/(.*)....(\.jpg)$/mv & \1\2/'
mv 006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg 006103insettedryshampoo-blossom.jpg
mv 008299bathmassagesponges-3packa1a4.jpg 008299bathmassagesponges-3pack.jpg
mv 008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste125d.jpg 008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste.jpg
mv 8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g1005.jpg 8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g.jpg
LsyHP 11:41:52 /tmp/test/img
kent$  ls -1|sed -r 's/(.*)....(\.jpg)$/mv & \1\2/'|sh
LsyHP 11:41:57 /tmp/test/img
kent$  ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 kent kent 120 Jan  4 11:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 kent kent 160 Jan  4 11:41 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 006103insettedryshampoo-blossom.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 008299bathmassagesponges-3pack.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent   0 Jan  4 11:41 8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution sir . But it is not removing the last 4 characters . Also how can i do it by looping ??

Comment: @Drudge what do you mean `it is not removing the last 4 characters`? why do you need loop? the `ls -1` will list all files and pipe to sed to do renaming.

Comment: yeah i have tried the command but it's not removing the last 4 charter of the filename. When i run the command i am getting the output as :              006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg
008299bathmassagesponges-3packa1a4.jpg
008507colgatetripleactiontoothpaste125d.jpg
8729teatreeoilantisepticcream25g1005.jpg

Comment: @Drudge the `ls|sed` generates `mv ...` cmd. If it looks good, do `ls|sed|sh`, this will do renaming.

Comment: @Drudge I added "how to" example in answer. to show how it worked.

Comment: thank you for the update but i am not getting the output as of your when i execute the second command of yours in my test_images folder. When i run the command without |sh at the end it is just listing the files.

Comment: @Drudge is your sed gnu sed? `sed --version|head -1`  also try `\ls -1|...` (the leading back slash)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99683/discussion-between-drudge-and-kent).

Answer (score 1):

Try this single method also

```
rename 's/....\.jpg$/.jpg/' 006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg
```

**OutPut:**

```
006103insettedryshampoo-blossom.jpg
```

Comment: is this "rename" the one from `util-linux`? if not, please add which "rename" tool should be installed to execute it. E.g. rename-perl etc.

Comment: Thank you. This was the easiest for me although i had to install it. For doing the same thing for multiple files, instead of having the filename on the last part of the command add in this case `*.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Another method, assuming all your files are `.jpg` you could simply remove the last 8 and replace with `.jpg`

```
echo "006103insettedryshampoo-blossom7096.jpg" |sed -r 's/.{8}$/.jpg/'
```